# How does a React component listen to global state changes and perform side effects without rendering the component?

Tags: reactjs

We use the useEffect hook to listen to global state changes and perform side effects based on the global state value.
This however re-renders the component every time the global state changes which is hard on performance.

To prevent the entire component from re-rendering. We have put the side effect inside a component that renders nothing. This however feels like a hack.

Here is a demonstration in pseudo code:

```js
function Demo(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div>
      <DemoSideEffects />
      ... a large amount of content that is expensive to render
    </div>
  );
}

/**
 * This component will re-render when isFetchingData changes value. 
 * Its positioned inside this component to avoid re-rendering the entire <Demo> component.
 */
function DemoSideEffects(): null {
  const { isFetchingData, revalidate } = useGlobalState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetchingData) {
      revalidate();
    }
  }, [isFetchingData]);

  return null;
}
```

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: [jotia](https://jotai.org/) seems to solve this problem, but it will need refactoring, and I am not sure but [useExternalStore](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usesyncexternalstore) could  also help

Comment: Hi, I am no React expert, but I think the method you are doing isn't hacky. It's one of the tricks to prevent rerendering of components that don't need to re-render.

Comment: This feels very hack-y, but the fix in this case probably isn't a few lines of code, but an architectural re-think of how you're managing your global state and how you're hooking your components into it. You may have a very special use case where this is the only way, but after like 7 years of working with React I've never seen or even **heard** of doing this, so it's setting off red flags in my head. Usually to help with performance you either refactor component trees to minimise re-rendering triggering, or use stuff like `React.memo` or the various memo hooks to prevent performance issues

Comment: But with such limited code, I can't really suggest architectural improvements. If you could make a super simple sandbox recreation of the problem you're trying to overcome then we could probably make suggestions on the proper React way of solving said issue

Comment: Thanks for coming into the conversation, @Jayce444! We used to do this in our old company. But I'm just an entry level React programmer, so I don't know any better.